# ALFA AWUS036NH and ALFA AWUS036ACH adapters showing weird interface name and unable to use any commands with them

Tags: 16.04, networking, realtek-wireless, alfa-wireless

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have connected an Alfa AWUS036NH and AWUS036ACH wireless USB adapter. When I use `ifconfig`, it shows the interface as `wlx00c0ca5a4f9d`, and if I try `ifconfig wlx00c0ca5a4f9d down`, it says the operation is not permitted.

Is there any reason for this? When I use my internal network card it shows as `wlan0` if that is any help.

```
wlx00c0ca5a4f9d Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:5a:4f:9d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface name is "weird" because of the introduction of predictable interface naming. Please see: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ The name of your wireless interface, *wlx00c0ca5a4f9d*, suggests that it is a WireLess interface, that it is eXternal and the unique identifier is its MAC address. In future Ubuntu versions, your internal device will be renamed to something like *wlp3s0*, suggesting a WireLess PCI interface at PCI bus 03:00.0.

Taking an interface up or down is not permitted by ordinary users. If you are a privileged user, that is, if you have the sudo password, then you may do:

```
sudo ifconfig wlx00c0ca5a4f9d down
```